# How do I escape an ampersand in a Socrata SODA 2 API call?

Tags: api, socrata

How do I escape `&` in a Socrata SODA 2 API call?

For example,

[http://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/xh8b-g55w.json?$where=license_description='Special Event Beer & Wine'&$limit=1](http://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/xh8b-g55w.json?%24where=license_description=%27Special%20Event%20Beer%20&%20Wine%27&%24limit=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the `&` as hex code `%26`.

[http://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/xh8b-g55w.json?$where=license_description='Special Event Beer %26 Wine'&$limit=1](http://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/xh8b-g55w.json?%24where=license_description=%27Special%20Event%20Beer%20&%20Wine%27&%24limit=1)

Answer (score 1):

Correct, you can also URL encode the whole $where parameter if you want to.